# Cannot unapprove a WordPress comment

Tags: comments

My client approved a comment in WordPress that she shouldn't have.  I cannot for the life of me find a way to get rid of the approved comment, and it [appears that there really isn't a way](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/the-ability-to-unapprove-commenters).

I can sort the approved comments, but nowhere is there a checkbox by a specific comment to delete, unaprove, edit, spam or access/modify the comment in any way.

Does anyone have a workaround for this? As you can see by the screenshot, I can narrow down the list to just the one comment, but that is it.

Checking the boxes and using the drop-down menu doesn't actually affect the comment.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See that `bulk actions` dropdown in lower left? Choose your action there and then click `Apply`

Answer (score 0):

We finally figured this out.  The comments that could not be deleted were imported with posts/comments from a blogger site.  These comments were not attached/related to any posts though.  So they had to be hand-edited out of the database.